# Websphere WAS is creating new JSESSIONID after Session timeout instead of invalidating the session

Tags: websphere, session-timeout, jsessionid, was

When I log in, a new session is getting created properly with new jsessionid (SSO login). It is a clustered WAS. I have a session timeout value of 30 minutes. So after 30 minutes inactivity, my session is getting destroyed properly. I expect the user to prompt login again after the session timeout. But the issue is, it is not prompting the user to log in, instead, it is going inside without any issue.

on checking the logs, I found my previous session is getting destroyed properly, but when the user clicks something after 30 minutes, automatically a new session id is getting created, which is incorrect. Kindly suggest whether any setting in websphere was or any approach to avoid this after session timeout.

Logs:

```
Current session :UJ8IzrhI7-E8oSRtg1PdbSY
After 30 minutes
New session :o6fPgTstd3ytRb2xrsxkRBU (automatically) -  dont know from where i am getting this

2020-01-26 **18:35:08**,307 [WebContainer : 67]  ***** Browser : End Request *************************************************

2020-01-26 **18:35:08,307** [WebContainer : 67]  Browser : End Request *************************************************
2020-01-26 **19:07:18,019** [WsSessionInvalidatorThread] DEBUG com.t24browser.servlets.BrowserSessionListener  - Session Destroyed : Id = **UJ8IzrhI7-E8oSRtg1PdbSY**

2020-01-26 **19:07:18,019** [WsSessionInvalidatorThread] DEBUG com.t24browser.servlets.BrowserSessionListener  - Clearing Session Data : Id = UJ8IzrhI7-E8oSRtg1PdbSY

2020-01-26 19:08:02,571 [WebContainer : 140] DEBUG com.t24browser.servlets.BrowserServlet  - ***** Browser : Start Request ***********************************************

2020-01-26 **19:08:02**,571 [WebContainer : 140] DEBUG com.t24browser.servlets.BrowserServlet  - 
 *** Session Data *** 
      - Id = o6fPgTstd3ytRb2xrsxkRBU
      - Sign On Name = 
      - User Id = 
      - Token = 
      - Token Seq No =
```

Comment: What authentication method are you using? Make sure you are using FORM. If you use BASIC (popup in browser) you want be able to relogin, as browser caches the authentication header and resends it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the request header to no-cache, no-transform, no-private on IHS. Because the browser of use end is reusing that.